# How to summarize list columns with multiple value selections

Tags: column, multiple-values, statistics

What are the recommended method to create summaries/statistics from list columns with multiple value selections? Are there any reporting server tools which can easily split the values and separate into related tables or lists for further analysis?

I've done this manually, exporting to csv and breaking up using regexes, but I imagine there must be better ways of handling this.

Powershell/programmatic access might be a solution, but that would take a lot of custom work for every list

Comment: Could you be more specific? Where do you want to see the summary? In dispform? in a custom page? How do you want to see the summary? as value1 | value2 | value3?

Comment: I really do not have any specific wishes, only experience many users are working with multi-selects, and I do not relly have a simple/good solution to summarize the data.